# Creating CUSTOM RULE in conditional formatting to search column contents and highlight row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm looking to find one word inside cells in column E with multiple words, and when it's found format that whole row.

I am so lost...

This is as close as I got `=$E201=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(E:E), "final")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `A2:Z`:

```
=regexmatch($E2, "(?i)final")
```